# Service Error: ContactApp: Mismatch

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is the error:

> Service error: ContactsApp: Mismatch: etags = ["RX44ejVSLit7I2A9WhJWFkoLRAM."], version = [1345671373905000]

My App Script app runs well when I'm the one executing the script, but when another person executes the script, I get the error above. I have set all executing permissions as required.

Comment: tried to follow this: http://goo.gl/tpZv2, I'll update on how it goes...

Comment: So the Utilities.sleep() trick kinda works! ref to link above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GAS team is aware of this problem for both Contacts and Calendar.

Depending on the time you set for sleep(), it may periodically work. It appears to be related to server load.

Breaking into two scripts has worked well for me. First script is where the contact data is accepted or created. That script pushes the data into a database (I used ScriptDb). Each field to be added to the contact is a separate record and has reference to the contact it needs to be added to.

A second script, on a trigger, checks the database for any new data. It iterates through the database trying to add a field for each contact. You use try()...catch() on each attempt to add the field. Note: do not use sleep() with this process, your script may timeout.

Of course, you could just wait until GAS fixes the problem.

Comment: @ProfNandaa you are welcome. There are two things you should do. If you like a person's answer, accept it. This means click on the check mark for this answer so it shows up as answered and accepted. The other thing that can help is to star the issue in Google's issue tracker here: [Issue Tracker Id 1528](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1528). Google's team uses the number of stars to prioritize issues. Cheers.